# jQuery show/hide slider not working in jQuery 1.5.x?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following script here: http://8wayrun.com/wiki/algol/

```
XenForo.register('.ToggleContents', 'XenForo.ToggleContents');

XenForo.ToggleContents = function($toc)
{
    var hideText = 'hide';
    var showText = 'show';
    var isVisible = true;

    $toc.ready(function() {
        $toc.find(':first').append('<span class="toggle">(<a href="#">'+hideText+'</a>)</span>');
    });

    $toc.find('.toggle:first').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (isVisible = !isVisible)
        {
            $toc.find('.toggle a:first').html(hideText);
            $toc.find('.contents:first').slideDown();
        }
        else
        {
            $toc.find('.toggle a:first').html(showText);
            $toc.find('.contents:first').slideUp();
        }
    });
}
```

Its pretty simple what it does. The first thing it does is attach a `<span class="toggle">hide</a>` link to any div with the ".ToggleContents" class... this works perfect.

The next thing it does is take the link it just created, prevents the default function and changes it into a hide/show link instead. This was working GREAT in jQuery 1.4.x. However, in jQuery 1.5.x it doesn't work at all. The `e.preventDefault()` is never run...

Which tells me that `.find('.toggle:first')` is not working in 1.5.x. Does anyone know what I should be using now?

Comment: Are you sure the .toggle:first elements exist in the DOM when the $toc.find().click() is handled? Might be that at the time jQuery is trying to find '.toggle:first' elements to bind the click handler, they are not yet created. You can use console.log() in Firefox and Webkit browsers to check if they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... in 1.5.x this was required, but not in 1.4.x... very weird.

What I did was move the `$toc.find('.toggle:first').click(function(e)` to INSIDE the `$toc.ready(function()`, now everything is working wonderfully.